# leading field camel bindy

Tags: csv, apache-camel, bindy

I use Camel Bindy and @FixedLengthRecord strategy .

I have a field :

```
@DataField(pos=21, length=6, trim=true,align="R")
private BigDecimal refundCount
```

and I want leading this field zeros.
What can I do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting paddingChar='0'

Comment: Yes, I tried but it did not work properly . I always could use StringUtils.leftPad or rightPad but I think that Camel Bindy allows on leading in better way.

Comment: Ok , My fault I used csv.CSVDataFormat instead of fixed.BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.